# Vertical spacing between DIVs

Tags: css

I have some extra vertical spacing between the rows of my 3x3 grid of DIVs and I don't know why.  Can somebody help me out here:

```css
.tinybox {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  border: solid 1px #999;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 1px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="tinybox"></div>
<div class="tinybox"></div>
<div class="tinybox"></div>
<br style="clear:both" />
<div class="tinybox"></div>
<div class="tinybox"></div>
<div class="tinybox"></div>
<br style="clear:both" />
<div class="tinybox"></div>
<div class="tinybox"></div>
<div class="tinybox"></div>
<br style="clear:both" />
```

I have tried line-height, but that does nothing.

Comment: Remove `<br>` tags, they create extra spaces. I suggest to move away from floats, since there is great support for flex and css grid already

Comment: Thanks @Justinas - You pointed me to the culprit - I added a display:block to the <br>.  That fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear float without `br`

```css
.tinybox {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  border: solid 1px #999;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 1px;
  float: left;
}

.tinybox:nth-child(3n + 1) {
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<div class="tinybox"></div>
<div class="tinybox"></div>
<div class="tinybox"></div>
<div class="tinybox"></div>
<div class="tinybox"></div>
<div class="tinybox"></div>
<div class="tinybox"></div>
<div class="tinybox"></div>
<div class="tinybox"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:grid` to create similar layout, and use `grid-column-gap` and `grid-row-gap` to control the gap / spacing more easier.

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
}

.child{
 border:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
  <div class="child">5</div>
  <div class="child">6</div>
  <div class="child">7</div>
  <div class="child">8</div>
  <div class="child">9</div>
<div>
```